# Cannot construct MessageQueue object for journal queue

Tags: c#, windows, message-queue

I am unable to construct a [MessageQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue?view=netframework-4.8) object to access a target journal queue used by one of my applications.

When I execute

```cs
MessageQueue journalQ = new MessageQueue("my_computer\\private$\\test queue")
```

I can construct a messagequeue.

I have verified that test queue exists and it has a journal queue that is enabled and has a message.

When I execute

```cs
MessageQueue journalQ = new MessageQueue("my_computer\\private$\\test queue\\Journal$")
```

I cannot construct the queue, when looking at my locals I get `MessageQueueException` exceptions thrown saying `The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.`

I have tried multiple different path fomrat combinations, both the full "Format=OS" and more dissected strings, and ";journal" rather than "\journal"

```
string journalPath = (messageQueueList[choiceInt].Path.Split(':')[2].Split('$')[0]
                      + "$"
                      + messageQueueList[choiceInt].Path.Split('$')[1]
                      + "\\Journal$"
                     );

journalQ = new MessageQueue(journalPath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly send messages to a journal queue, you can only receive from those. Accessing sending-related members of a journal's `MessageQueue` object will throw the exception you cited in your question. Take the following example code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create queue
    string queueName = "computer_name\\private$\\test queue";
    MessageQueue.Create(queueName);

    // Create MessageQueue object and enable journal
    MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
    queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    queue.UseJournalQueue = true;
    Console.WriteLine($"queue.CanRead = {queue.CanRead}");
    Console.WriteLine($"queue.CanWrite = {queue.CanWrite}");

    // Send message
    queue.Send("test message");

    // Receive message from queue
    // The message is copied to the journal now
    Console.WriteLine($"queue.Receive(): {(string)queue.Receive().Body}");

    // Receive message again from journal
    MessageQueue journal = new MessageQueue(queueName + "\\Journal$");
    journal.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    Console.WriteLine($"journal.CanRead = {journal.CanRead}");
    Console.WriteLine($"journal.CanWrite = {journal.CanWrite}");
    Console.WriteLine($"journal.Receive(): {(string)journal.Receive().Body}");
}
```

This will create a new message queue and enable the matching journal queue. A sent message is stored in the message queue; after receiving it, it is moved to the journal queue. You can then receive this message a second time from the journal queue.

The program's output is:

```
queue.CanRead = True
queue.CanWrite = True
queue.Receive(): test message
journal.CanRead = True
journal.CanWrite = False
journal.Receive(): test message
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, vielen vielen Dank Jan, I was not constructing a Queue but working off of an existing one. You helped me identify that the exceptions will not block Pop() and Peek() operations on the constructed object, the following code works:

```c#
journalQ = new MessageQueue("my_computer\\private$\\test queue\\Journal$");
journalQ.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll();
journalQ.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new string[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
Console.WriteLine($"journal.Peek(): {(string)journalQ.Peek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Body.ToString()}");

```

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you :)

Comment: I just saw that you unaccepted this answer again - is there anything missing?